# Similar thing in Azure like ebextensions in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, deployment

I am using [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) in my AWS enviroment to configure my machine instances to perform some custom actions, like intalling NewRelic, changing IIS idle timeout to 0. I can run cmd actions  after my app been deploied.

There is something like this in Azure Cloud Services?

Comment: a little search gives this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx

Comment: @trailmax oh, thanks, that is it :D. Can you answer in question so I can mark your answer as right answer?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Azure supports startup tasks: you can run cmd or any other executable, including installing NewRelic.

Here is the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx

By the way, NewRelic has a nuget  package for Azure Cloud Services - it configures the installation itself (mostly).